# Identifying rasters with specific attribute value that intersect polygon using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, select-by-attribute, overlay, intersect

I have numerous raster files that each contain an attribute field "VALUE" that can take on the values 0 or 1.

How can I identify rasters that have any of their "VALUE=1" cells intersecting a focal polygon (this same polygon will be used for all rasters)?

I included a picture in case it helps. My bounding, spatial extent polygon is shown in tan and a single raster is displayed alongside it, whereby black ("0") cells do not contain the focal fish species of interest and blue ("1") cells do contain the focal species. I only care about raster-polygon intersection for "VALUE=1" cells in each raster (i.e., the fish species occurs within my focal study extent). I'm willing to convert all rasters to shapefiles if that leads to a more efficient tool.

[image]

Comment: For questions involving ArcPy (ArcGIS automation) please always include a code snippet that lets us see what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The problem is I don't even know what tool to use to get a code snippet... Do you know of any forums where my question might be acceptable... that can at least get me started...

Comment: I recommend that you edit out "identify an automated method", replace the ArcPy tag with one for ArcGIS Desktop, and focus your question on finding the tool that you seek, so that it can be re-opened here (where I think it has the best chance of being answered).

Comment: OK, I'll do that.  Thank you.  I have searched online for a few hours today, tried Model Builder, etc. and still can't figure it out!  Uggh....

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I just re-edited my question... hopefully more suitable.  I've been doing GIS for years and am not looking for a GIS tutor, but I get your point.

Comment: You may find it worthwhile to review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 - the skill of asking focussed questions is one that I think is well worth all of us honing to help the flow of quick and accurate answers.